# How to set priority for two custom module in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, module, dependency

I have created two custom module in magento and use `sales_order_place_after` event in both module.

For example first module is `Custom_Guest`(community) and second is `Assel_Sms` (local). `sales_order_place_after` event in `Assel_Sms` execute first and then Custom_Guest but I want to execute `sales_order_place_after` event of `Assel_Sms` after `Custom_Guest` event.

**Custom_Guset.xml** code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Guest>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Assel_Sms />
            </depends>
        </Custom_Guest>
    </modules>
</config>
```

How to execute `Assel_Sms` plugin's event after `Custom_Guest` plugin's event execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Assel_Sms.xml` add

```
<depends>
   <Custom_Guest />
</depends>
```

This mean that your `Assel_Sms` module configuration will be loaded after the `Custom_Guest` configuration.

Comment: The Assel_Sms.xml is the module configuration file in app/etc/modules?

Comment: Yes, app/etc/modules is the location